# How to access current_user in stimulus_reflex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs, stimulus-reflex

In this reflex I want to set the lastupdateby field to the current_user. I haven't been able to get it to work. Is there something I need to do to get that value in a reflex? Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong? If I hard code the value instead of current_user it works. I must just be referencing it wrong.

```
def toggle
 todo = Todo.find(element.dataset[:id])
 todo.update(completed_at: (todo.completed_at? ? nil : Time.current), lastUpdatedBy: current_user)
end
```

Comment: Ref :- https://headway.io/blog/a-future-for-rails-stimulusreflex, you have to add `delegate :current_user, to: :connection`

Comment: That was it. Thanks! Got it working.

Comment: @Salil why not add this as an answer, so people can upvote and OP can accept it. This way it will be more visible to other user :-)

Comment: @RolandStuder: Sure, Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ref [this](https://headway.io/blog/a-future-for-rails-stimulusreflex),

Add following line in your reflex class.

```
delegate :current_user, to: :connection
```